# Splitting JS into multiple source files

Tags: javascript

Apologies in advance, I have a pretty dumb/basic question about JS.

I am trying to link a script (defined in a separate JS file) to a button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
     
<input type="button" id="button" value="Button">

<script>
  button.onclick = function() {
    alert('Clicked!');
  };
</script>
     
  </body>
</html
```

`myscripts.js` has jus this:

```
function x (){
alert("external fn clicked");
console.log("running x");
}
```

When I try to replace the invocation of function in `index.html` to `button.onclick = x();` things stop working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're *calling* x in the assignment, not assigning x as the handler. Also, you don't define button anywhere. Also also, recommend using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener): `const button = document.getElementById("button"); button.addEventListener("click", x);` Last but certainly not least, *always check the console for errors before anything else*. You would have seen the reference error about button being undefined if you'd looked before posting.

Comment: @JaredSmith Not necessarily. In some (most?) browsers when you add an id to an element the element becomes available in the global scope because it gets attached to `window`. Therefor there would be no error about button being undefined.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you very much!! this worked. Definitely re console - I'd actually looked in the console before posting, it was completely blank - looked like it was just failing to recognize the existence of the source file

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the onclick to a function, however it seems what you're doing is setting it to the return value of the x function, which is `undefined`.

Simply change `button.onclick = x()` to `button.onclick = x`.

Also in modern times it's usually preferable to use [`button.addEventListener(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script>
    function x() {
      alert("external fn clicked");
      console.log("running x");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" id="button" value="Button">

  <script>
    button.onclick = x;
  </script>

</body>
</html
```

Comment: thank you! I'd actually tried this but could never get it to work if function x is defined in a separate file, it only works if function body is defined in index.html header. What do I need to edit to make this method work with x within myscripts.js?

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit anything. All js loaded as script tags should be global unless you have `type=module` on it.